# Using a default Powershell within the Integrated Powershell Window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using a default profile script for all my Powershell windows and it logs me in to all the different modules I need.  (Documents\WindowsPowerShell).  This continues to work well with VSC and under a normal default powershell window.

When I load up the Integrated PS window, it no longer leverages the default profile script.  Is there a way to point the Integrated PS window to use the same profile script I have always used?

Answer (score 0):

The integrated terminal uses a separate profile but under the same path as the PowerShell.exe profile: `Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1`

You can create the Code profile and simply add the below line and it will load your main profile each time it starts up. (But be aware that not everything plays nice in the integrated terminal, it is a custom host using the Powershell Editor Services).

```
. ((Join-Path -Path (Split-Path $profile) -ChildPath Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1))
```